# Can I save up dragon souls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can I save dragon souls or do I have to spend them before the next dragon will attack? It seems that I haven't seen a dragon in ages and I wonder if it is because I still have an unspent dragon soul?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. You need to manually unlock new shouts so they can be saved.

Dragon encounters, AFAIK, are totally random - I've got a stockpiled soul and found a dragon.

Comment: Part random, part not. Word Walls on the main world map have dragons defending them, and you encounter some in the main quest-line.