# How to Unlock New Shouts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dragon souls not activating new words](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words)

I have a few shouts that I am unable to equip.  Upon doing so I am prompted with `Dragon Souls are required to unlock shouts`.

I know I have absorbed more dragon souls than I have shouts. How do I "apply" the soul to the shout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must press the "Activate" button while the shout is selected in the menu (its "r" on PC). Your Available Dragon Souls are displayed at the bottom right. 
You must ofc first learn a new word of a shout before you can apply the soul. (These are found in the stone walls in the whole world)