# How do you actually get to use dragon shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dragon souls not activating new words](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words)

I have been killing dragons and gathering their souls like mad and have plenty of words. Why are they still grey? They keep saying that I need more souls and I have a lot of them. Confused.

How do you actually get to use dragon shouts?

Comment: @GMNoob the other one is probably this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35895/how-to-unlock-new-shouts  which is a dupe of the first one

Comment: The question is a duplicate but the chosen answer won't actually answer this question :P

Comment: Ah yx, yeah that was the question I was thinking of.  Odd that the correct answer to the more common version of this question isn't chosen as the correct answer in that original question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't help you with the exact button to press, but there is a strange UX issue here.  You need to press a special button (listed on the bottom of the screen) to actually activate the word.  If you just click on the grey word, it thinks you are trying to equip it and not learn it.

The error message is also very poor.

So in short, first learn the word with a special button (R) on the pc, and then try to equip it, and use the shout button (z) on the pc to use it.

Comment: What, a bad design decision in the Skyrim UI? That must be the only one! :P