# How to get a dragon soul for Bend Will?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had Bend Will, so I tried to unlock it because I have 22 dragon souls but it wouldn't let me unlock it.  I just went and killed a dragon but Miraak stole the soul from me. What do I do now?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE. Please edit your question to make it abit clear what you're asking. Are you having a problem unlocking a shout with dragon souls you allready have (in which case Miraak stealing your 23rd one doesn't have anything to do with it) or is your question about him stealing souls?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go [through the main quest line](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Bend_Will) of the dragonborn dlc to be able to unlock it. Once unlocked you can spend a dragon soul on it by clicking 'unlock' or pressing the according key. [This page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/i-have-9-dragon-souls-but-cannot-unlock-shouts-what-do-i-need-to-do) on the site covers that extensively and refers to other helpful pages.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get out of Raven Rock go back to skyrim. Fight dragons within that he useally doesn't take it unless your on his land.

Comment: This is not true. Miraak will still show up in Skyrim when killing dragons. Source: He stole my dragon soul south of Riften. Besides that, this doesn't answer the question.