# Why can't I unlock shout skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dragon souls not activating new words](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words)

I am curious why I get a message saying dragon souls are required to unlock shout however I currently have 5, how many drangon souls are required to unlock a shouts?

[image]

Comment: Are you pressing R?

Comment: Press R to UNLOCK , confirm the Dialog.
After that you will be able to use it.

Comment: If You choose another power, what happened?