# Skyrim Dragon Souls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dragon souls not activating new words](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words)

I've killed about 10 dragons but I only have 2 shouts that work and I have bots and pieces of six others. Are the dragon souls saving up for when I have all three parts of a new shout or are they just gone now?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! There are already several questions on the site about dragon souls in Skyrim; give me a minute and I will link the most appropriate one, if I can find it.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words

Comment: @Hackworth, thanks, that's it. GamerJ13, Stack Exchange sites work best when we have a single question that covers a particular topic, so I'm voting to close this as a duplicate because there is an existing question that should cover your situation.

Comment: Welcome mate. Thos shouts make you pretty wicked when you start building them up. I am missing three shout bits ...but have got a lot more than that in dragon souls. Dont make much sense to me that. Anyways - have fun here :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Gaming SE!

You have to unlock each word individually with a dragon soul in order to use it. That way, you can save your dragon souls for later, for the shouts you want, not necessarily the ones you get earlier.

To unlock a word, go to Magic -> Shouts, move the mouse/selection over the shout you want to unlock, and press the required button/key, displayed in the lower left.

Each shout has 3 words, and you automatically unlock them in order. Of course, you need both a dragon soul and the next locked word in a shout to advance that it.