# Can not unlock Bend Will shout

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have defeated about 5 or so dragons outside of solstheim and absorbed all their souls yet my Bend Will and other shouts still won't unlock. What do I need to do?

Comment: have you read this yet: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/dragon-souls-not-activating-new-words